# Freeing a tree in C

Tags: c, malloc, free, calloc

So I've been given the structure of a tree where each node has up to 2 children:

```
typedef struct one_node_t one_node_t;

typedef struct two_nodes_t two_nodes_t;

typedef struct my_tree_t {
  int numberOfNodes; //== 1 || numberOfNodes == 2

   // If the node is a leaf, it is represented by (*oneNode==NULL && numberOfNodes == 1)
    union {
       one_node_t* one;
       two_nodes_t* two;
    } nodeC;
} my_tree_t;

struct one_node_t {
  one_node_t* child;
};

struct two_node_t {
  my_tree_t children[2];
};
```

Now I was trying to write a function `void freeMyTree(my_tree_t* myTree)` which should free the allocated space of the tree `myTree` is pointing towards:

```
void freeMyTree(my_tree_t* myTree) {
  if(myTree->numberOfNodes == 2){
      freeMyTree(myTree->nodeC.two->children);
      freeMyTree(&myTree->nodeC.two->children[1]);
      free(myTree->nodeC.two);
      myTree->nodeC.two = NULL;
  }else{
      if(myTree->nodeC.one->child != NULL)
          freeMyTree(myTree->nodeC.one->child);
      free(myTree->nodeC.one);
      myTree->nodeC.one = NULL;
  }
}
```

But it seems like no space is freed. I guess there has to be some kind of misunderstanding of myself how to free up space, but googling didn't help me to understand it.

I think that space is not freed up because I create my files using gcc with the `-fsanitize=leak` option.

If I created a `my_tree_t* a = calloc(1, sizeof(my_tree_t))` earlier the `leak sanitizer` tells me if I did not free it. However after calling `freeMyTree(a)` it will still tell me the same thing.

**Edit:**
The error messages explcitly says that a one/two was not freed. Because they are point to lines like:

```
my_tree_t t;
t.nodeC.two = calloc(1, sizeof(two_nodes_t)); //<== POINTING TO THIS LINE
```

Comment: Don't you suspect that we might be at least moderately interested in knowing precisely how it is that you *think* that "no space is freed" ?

Comment: @MikeNakis Ohh, sorry. By the leak sanitizer. I will put a better description at the post.

Comment: And what does "So I've given" mean? Did you write this? Why? Or did you mean "So I've been given"? In this case, whoever gave it to you is no friend of yours.

Comment: @MikeNakis added. I've been given. I was looking for coding challenges for C beginners online. I guess I didn't find good ones then. Do you have any recommendations for that?

Comment: You are freeing something, but not all the nodes. The code is badly written. Use null as the terminating condition like this if(myTree == null) return; freeMyTree(child1); freeMyTree(child2); free(myTree).

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean I know that I can just change the structure to make it easier, but I want to understand my mistake here in order to get a better understanding of C. (As mentioned before the structure was given like this and so I could be given even worse things in the future.)

Comment: @oRookie I answered like 6 minutes ago.  Refresh the page.

Comment: Hint 1:  look at your compiler warnings. Hint 2: `struct one_node_t { one_node_t* child; };`  doesn't describe a tree with one child, it describes a linked list which carries no information in nodes, a.k.a. a base 1 number.

Comment: Don't retell error messages in free prose, copy and paste them exactly as they appear. Read on [mcve].

Comment: The structure design is awful.  It can be made to work, but that doesn't make it less awful.  The one node vs two node structures are bad.  There's also no way to have just a right child node; you can't give your tree shape,

Answer (score 0):

All the `free()`s that you do are `free(myTree->nodeC.one);` and `free(myTree->nodeC.two);`  but nowhere do I see you doing the following: `free(myTree->nodeC.one->child);`

Comment: That would just be if the child/children would also be calloced/malloced right? But they don't need to be, right?

Comment: Right, that don't need to be.  But it usually is.  And with the fragments of code that you have shown, and the behavior you are reporting, this is the explanation one can logically deduce.

Comment: I added some more info. I checked all leaks and none points to the child/children. Also I checked the code and I never calloced/malloced them.

Comment: `myTree->nodeC.two->children[0]` is not a pointer, so `free`in it won't quite work.

Comment: @n.m. you are right.  This code is so confusing.  I corrected my answer.  And still `struct one_node_t { one_node_t* child; };` does not make any sense.  Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tree where each node has up to 2 children. This is a tree where each node has either exactly two children, or no children at all and an associated base 1 natural number. Indeed,

```
struct one_node_t {
   one_node_t* child;
};
```

contains no subtrees. It is a linked list with no information in the nodes. The only information that such a list carries is its length. So this is an inefficient representation of some natural number. (We ignore the possibility of a looped linked list).

The correct way to free such list would be something like

```
one = myTree->one;
while (one) {
  tmp = one->child;
  free(one);
  one = tmp;
}
```